# Menu floats above menu button

Tags: python, tkinter

So to begin with here is my code:

```
from Tkinter import *

def hello():
    print "Hello"
root = Tk()
root.attributes('-fullscreen', 1)

icons = []
icons.append(PhotoImage(file="Icons\start.gif"))
icons.append(PhotoImage(file="Icons\quit.gif"))
icons.append(PhotoImage(file="Icons\save.gif"))
icons.append(PhotoImage(file="Icons\load.gif"))
icons.append(PhotoImage(file="Icons\Next.gif"))

screensizex = root.winfo_screenwidth()
screensizey = root.winfo_screenheight()

mainframe = Frame(root, height=(screensizey-(screensizey/20)), width=screensizex, bg="#50a9ad")
mainframe.grid(row=0)

menuframe = Frame(root, height=(screensizey/20), width=screensizex)
menuframe.grid(row=1, sticky="w")

startmenu = Menubutton ( menuframe,  text="Start", image=icons[0], compound = LEFT, relief=RAISED, 
    direction="above")
startmenu.grid(row=0, column=0)
startmenu.place(relx=0.03, rely=0.5, anchor=CENTER)
startmenu.menu = Menu(startmenu, tearoff=0)
startmenu["menu"] = startmenu.menu
startmenu.configure(font=("Arial", 8, "bold"))

startmenu.menu.add_command(label="Next Day", image = icons[4], compound = LEFT, command=hello)
startmenu.menu.add_separator()
startmenu.menu.add_command(label="Save", image = icons[2], compound = LEFT, command=hello)
startmenu.menu.add_command(label="Load", image = icons[3], compound = LEFT, command=hello)
startmenu.menu.add_separator()
startmenu.menu.add_command(label="Quit", image = icons[1], compound = LEFT, command=root.quit)
startmenu.menu.configure(font=("Arial", 8))

root.mainloop()
```

And here is what I get:
[GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4NJf.jpg)

As you can see the menu "Floats" above the menu button instead of just being above it.
I am not sure of what causes that but I can't figure out how to fix it. I am sure it's something pretty simple but I am a beginner with Python....
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I have only used a Menubutton with default direction 'down',  Is the posted code an mcve?  See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.  What if you remove icons, entries, or being fullscreen?

Comment: Hi, yes the code above is mcve or at least I believe so (it is complet, minimal and verifiable). Removing icons doesn't change anything, I tried to modify the entries but it's the same.
If I put the direction to down the menu covers the button wich doesn't look too good...it's a little better but not exactly what I want...

Comment: Do you really mean that it you remove a single item from the popup, such as the one for 'Quit', then the program works correctly and the popup is where you want and expect it?

Comment: No, I tried adding or removing items but it doesn't change anything, the menu still floats way above the button

Comment: If you remove things and nothing changes, then the code is not minimal.  'Minimal' means that any significant removal either breaks or fixes the code.  This must not be explained very well on the page I referenced, as beginners seem not to understand.  The opposite approach is to start with the bare minimum and try to get that to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be with putting the menu button on the absolute bottom.  Here is near minimal code, with menu button one 'line' up from bottom, that works with 3.6 (tk 8.6) on Win10

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
root.attributes('-fullscreen', 1)
tk.Button(root, text='Close', command=root.destroy).pack()
mb = tk.Menubutton(root, text='Menu', direction='above')
#mb.pack(side='bottom')
tk.Label(root, text='Filler2').pack(side='bottom')
mb.pack(side='bottom')
tk.Label(root, text='Filler1').pack(side='bottom')
menu = tk.Menu(mb, tearoff=0)
menu.add_command(label='Popup', command=lambda:print('hello'))
mb['menu'] = menu
```

Popup is on top of Filler1.  Move the bottom down to the bottom (by commenting and uncommenting pack lines) and popup is in same place, leaving a gap.  I tried using a ttk Menubutton instead and got the same behavior.  I then went to the [official Tk docs](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/contents.htm) and discovered the 'flush' direction which puts the box 'over' the button.  For tk, this means means 'on top of so as to cover the button'.  For ttk, it means 'flush against the top, leaving the button exposed', which is what you want.  So the solution, as least on Windows with tk 8.6 is to create the button with

```
mb = ttk.Menubutton(root, text='Menu', direction='flush')
```